# Erro ao usar o index para pegar um indice em especifico

Tags: python

Gostaria de pegar a posição de onde o maior valor digitado está dentro da lista. Estou tentando com o index mais não estou conseguindo.

```
for c in range(0, 5):
    num.append(int(input('Digite 5 valores: ')))
    if c < 1:
        maior += num[0]
        menor += num[0]

    for val in num:
        if val >= maior:
            posmaior += val.index()
            maior = 0
            maior += val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você está querendo implementar um código que seja capaz de montar uma lista com **5** valores, verificar o elemento de maior valor e, em seguida, especificar o índice deste valor.

Pois bem, quando você faz:

```
for c in range(0, 5):
    num.append(int(input('Digite 5 valores: ')))
```

O código captura o valor digitado e tenta inserir em um objeto **num**. Objeto este, que deveria ser definido anteriormente e que fosse do tipo **lista**. Só que você não o definiu anteriormente. Portanto o tal objeto - lista - não poderá ser alimentado.

Outra coisa, Python já disponibiliza uma função para calcular o valor máximo de uma lista. Neste caso a função é **max()**.

Além disso, para você relacionar índice com valor você pode utilizar a função **enumerate**.

Prestando atenção à estas observações você pode implementar o seguinte código:

```
num = list()
for i in range(1, 6):
    num.append(int(input(f'Digite o {i}º valor: ')))

maior = max(num)

for indice, item in enumerate(num):
    if item == maior:
        print(f'O maior valor é {item} e possui índice {indice}')
        break
```

Observe que o primeiro **for** montará uma lista com os 5 valores passados. Já o segundo **for** irá percorrer a lista **num** e verificará o item cujo índice possui valor maior. E, caso este item tenha o valor maior exibirá o respectivo item e índice.

Observe também que este código tem um **break**. Este, servirá para interromper a execução do segundo **for** quando ele encontrar o item de valor máximo.

Agora, se a lista tiver mais de um item de maior valor, você pode retirar o break.

Deste modo o código ficará

```
num = list()
for i in range(1, 6):
    num.append(int(input(f'Digite o {i}º valor: ')))

maior = max(num)

for indice, item in enumerate(num):
    if item == maior:
        print(f'O maior valor é {item} e possui índice {indice}')
```

Neste último código poderemos listar todos os valores da lista que, porventura, tenha maior valor.

---

Agora, se você deseja capturar todos os valores a partir de um só input(). Você pode implementar o seguinte código:

```
num = list(map(int, input('Digite os 5 valores: ').split()))

maior = max(num)
for indice, item in enumerate(num):
    if item == maior:
        print(f'O maior valor é {item} e possui índice {indice}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os 5 valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar todos os **5** valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A partir deste momento os valores digitados serão montados na lista de nome **num**. Posteriormente será calculado o maior valor (max()) e, em seguida, é exibido o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, tentei rodar o seu código, mas apareceram algumas mensagens de erro. A lista "num" não está definida, assim como outras variáveis como "maior". Também acredito que pode não ser uma boa ideia adicionar todos os números de uma vez sem determinar a criação de uma segunda lista ou algo do gênero.

Aqui vai uma alternativa bem simples para você.

```
num = []

print("Digite 5 valores.\n")

#Loop para que o usuário digite os 5 valores
z = 1
for i in range(5):
   n = int(input("Digite o valor " + str(z) + ": "))
   num.append(n)
   z += 1

num2 = sorted(num) '''Aqui, criei uma segunda lista, na qual adiciono os elementos da 
primeira lista e os organizo em ordem crescente com a função sorted(), de modo que o 
último elemento,
ou seja, o quarto (pois a lista é contada a partir do 0), será o maior.
'''

posição = num.index(num2[4]) '''Procurando último elemento da lista 2, que equivale ao 
maior da lista 1'''

#Exibindo o resultado
print("\nA posição do maior valor é a ", posição, ", mas, \
lembre-se de que a contagem dos elementos da lista começa a partir do 0, portanto, o 
maior elemento é o", posição + 1, "º.")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = []                                          #Inicia a lista de coleta de dados.

print('Digite 5 valores.')
for c in range(1, 6):                             #Iterando em c pelos números de 1 a 5...
  while(True):                                    #...inicia um laço de coleta de dado...
    try:                                          #...inicia um bloco de tratamento de exceções... 
      num.append(int(input(f'nº{c}: ')))          #...coleta, converte e adiciona dado a lista.
      break;                                      #...se não ha erros abandona o laço.
    except ValueError:                            #...caso ha um erro permanece no laço.
      print("Valor inválido, digite novamente")

k = lambda t: t[1]                                #função que orientará min() e max() a o que comparar.
maior = max(enumerate(num),key=k)                 #Obtem o maior elemento de num junto do seu índice
menor = min(enumerate(num),key=k)                 #Obtem o menor elemento de num junto do seu índice.

print(f"Da lista {num}:")
print(f"* o maior elemento é o {maior[1]} no índice {maior[0]}")
print(f"* o menor elemento é o {menor[1]} no índice {menor[0]}")
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/pUXgPj)</sup>

Sempre que coletar uma dado verifique se esse dado, seja direto do usuário, seja dum arquivo, de um pipe, da internet,.... seja qual for a fonte esse dado provavelmente ele precisa ser tratado antes de ser trabalhado dentro do seu programa.
O seu programa irá receber uma entrada do usuário via teclado onde o seu código foi projetado para lidar apenas com números inteiros, caso o usuário forneça como entrada algo diferente de um inteiro o programa para de funcionar.

Em situações criticas, as porções de código que podem fazer o seu programa parar de funcionar devem ser colocadas em dentro um bloco de tratamento de exceções cujo em python é definido pela declaração [try/except](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

Quanto ao funcionamento do código não tem segredos ele usa as funções embutidas [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) e [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), auxiliadas por `k`, para encontrar o menor e maior valor dentro da enumeração da lista `num`.

A enumeração é obtida com a função embutida [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) que apenas retorna um sequencia de tuplas `(indice, valor)` extraída de `num`.

A função `k` é um auxiliar para `min()` e `max()` apenas compararem os valores da enumeração.

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi dito pelos outros usuários, com o uso do `max()` , você acha em uma linha o maior valor dentro da lista. Também foi mencionado o uso do `enumerate()` como forma de iterar um array mantendo o index. A partir daí, é possível fazer uma list comprehension da lista enumerada, buscando os indexes dos números de maior valor. Dessa maneira, o código fica assim:

```
nums = list()

for i in range(0, 5):
    nums.append(int(input(f'Insira o {i + 1}o número: ')))

'''
Aqui se define o maior valor para
que não seja repetida a função max
'''
maior_valor = max(nums)
maiores_index = [index for index, i in enumerate(nums) if i == maior_valor]

print(f'O(s) maior(es) número(s) da lista é(são) o(s) de index {maiores_index}')
```

Se o uso da list comprehension te confundiu, é possivel também usar um for loop comum, o código fica assim:

```
nums = list()

for i in range(0, 5):
    nums.append(int(input(f'Insira o {i + 1}o número: ')))

maior_valor = max(nums)
maiores_index = list()

for index, num in enumerate(nums):
    if num == maior_valor:
        maiores_index.append(index)

print(f'O(s) maior(es) número(s) da lista é(são) o(s) de index {maiores_index}')
```